# VB Run Time Error '1004': Unable to get the Add property of the Addins class

Tags: excel, vba

I inherited an excel file that installs an addin off of a network folder for analysts at my company. This file works for nearly everyone who uses it. Recently, two analysts have been getting the error "Run Time Error '1004': Unable to get the Add property of the Addins class"

Code:

```
Sub InstallAddIn()
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    
    Dim AI As Excel.AddIn
    Set AI = Application.AddIns.Add(Filename:="\\apps\www\net\wwwroot\b-ratings\research\tools\addin\RMTools.xlam")
    AI.Installed = True 
End Sub
```

Please let me know if there are any additional details needed

Comment: Have you tried adding the `CopyFile` argument?  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.addins.add  Also see here for possible hints http://www.vbaexpress.com/forum/archive/index.php/t-13532.html